# Is there no cite tag to generate a bibtex MISC entry for answers on Cross Validated?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, papers

I would like to cite a response by whuber to generate correlated binomials: 
[Generating correlated binomial random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/generating-correlated-binomial-random-variables).

On other sites in the SO family (math ones) you can generate a cite key for a bib file (latex). Is there no such equivalent link-or method to automatically generate a bibtex entry on cross validated?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Yes, some sites have this facility set up (I believe physics does as well)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[CV shows up in papers sometimes](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=stats.stackexchange.com), so I turned on the citation option this morning:

[image: New cite link]

This option should make it just a bit easier to reference the great work you all are doing here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jon! This will help me a bunch, and many others I'm sure.