# Are CV citations indexed?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that CV questions have a "cite" option that returns the BibTeX citation of the question. I just did a quick search in StackOverflow and Data Science SE and none of them have this option.

- How does this work?
- Are they indexed later?
- Why does CV have this option while others don't?

Comment: Those are citations for scientific publications.  I suppose the other sites haven't asked to have that feature implemented, presumably because it's less of an issue.

Comment: Basically, this thread is why we have a "cite" button -- we asked and SE implemented it. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/is-there-no-cite-tag-to-generate-a-bibtex-misc-entry-for-answers-on-cross-valida Other sites haven't asked/SE hasn't chosen to implement it for them.

Comment: related post https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6414/56940

Comment: Different sites have different functionalities, e.g. some sites support $\TeX$, some don't, StackOverflow.com has interactive code snippets, we don't, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- How does this work?

Clicking the "cite" button populates some elements of the webpage to BibTeX and amsrefs citation formats.

- Are they indexed later?

Indexed where? For whom? For what purpose? Some service somewhere probably scrapes these citations. On the other hand, these citations don't appear in Google Scholar, either because this Q&A site doesn't fit Google Scholar's criteria for inclusion, or Google simply hasn't gotten around to including it.

- Why CV has this option while others don't?

Basically, this thread is why we have a "cite" button -- we asked and SE implemented it: [Is there no cite tag to generate a bibtex MISC entry for answers on Cross Validated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/is-there-no-cite-tag-to-generate-a-bibtex-misc-entry-for-answers-on-cross-valida) Other sites haven't asked for citation buttons, or SE has not chosen to implement it for them.